# NFS denies mount, even though the client is listed in exports

Tags: permissions, nfs, hpc

We have a couple of servers (part of an HPC cluster) in which we're currently seeing some NFS behavior which is not making sense to me.  node1 exports its `/lscratch` directory via NFS to node2, mounted at `/scratch/node1`.  node2 also exports its own `lscratch`, which is correspondingly mounted at `/scratch/node2` on node1.

Unfortunately, whenever I attempt to mount either NFS export on the opposite node, I get the following error:

`mount: node1:/lscratch failed, reason given by server: Permission denied`

This despite the fact that I  have included first the IP range (10.6.0.0) and then the specific IPs (10.6.7.1, 10.6.7.2) in /etc/exports.

Any suggestions?

**Edit to remove ambiguity**: I've made sure that exports only contains either the range, or the specific IPs, not both at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

A couple (perhaps silly) questions:

What's the export line?

What user is trying to mount the export?

root may not be allowed to mount...check into no root squash if this turns out to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

1. try putting the client's IP address in /etc/hosts.allow  (tcp wrappers, see man page)
2. from the client try telnet SERVER-IP 2049.... until that works, (for opening a connection)
   the mount won't work. (assuming default recent linux nfs setup,i.e. tcp also or only).
3. between making any changes like above, tell the nfs server about the changes with:

sudo exportfs -v -a

Comment: Adding the IP to hosts.allow did not change the behavior.  `telnet node-ip 2049` did not work on the client, but there is no firewall so I'm not sure what this diagnostic tells me.

Comment: Output of 'rpcinfo -p' on server? Any other error messages or warnings in your syslogs?